# Recovering a signal that was upsampled by non-integer factor

Tags: downsampling, resampling, multirate

I have a data sequence $G[n]$ that is upsampled at the transmitter of a communication system by a non-integer factor ($1.5$ to be precise). At the receiver, I am supposed to downsample the data and recover the sequence $G[n]$.

In MATLAB, I am implementing both the transmit and receive signals. When I upsample the signal $G[n]$ by integer factors at the transmitter and then downsample the received signal by the same integer factors, I am able to successfully recover the exact $G[n]$, and continue further processing.

However, when I upsample $G[n]$ by a non-integer factor $1.5$, and then downsample the received data by the same factor $1.5$, I do not get the exact sequence $G[n]$ that was transmitted. In MATLAB, for the transmitted sequence, I simply used commands `upsample` with factor $3$ and `downsample` with factor $2$. At the receiver I upsampled by factor $2$ and then downsampled by factor $3$.

Is there a way to recover the exact sequence $G[n]$ at the receiver even if it was upsampled by a non-integer factor at the transmitter?

~ryan

Comment: How different are they? If the samples are off by a very small number, you're probably seeing floating-point arithmetic artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

The **Sampling** operation (both upsample and downsample) depends on two very critical conditions:

1- The **existance** and applicability of ideal frequency selective filters

2- The operated signal being strictly **bandlimited**

For most practical systems these two critical conditions are only **approximately** met. Hence the computational results by those practical systems are only approximate and not exact.

Note that in case of simple but **crude** interpolation (upsampling) by **zero-order hold**, which requires no filter at all as being just a sample replication, you can exactly recover the original samples due to the simplicity of the operation.

Unless some advanced algorithms are utilized, therefore, some **deviation** (but controllable) is expected at the output of any practical sample rate conversion systems.

Answer (score 1):

The matlab functions `upsample` and `downsample` just insert zeros, and remove samples respectively. There are big aliasing/imaging problems with using them for fractional resampling that you probably are seeing. (Those imaging and aliasing problems are still there at non-fractional rates too, but happen to cancel each other out specifically when you `upsample` and then `downsample`)

You can use `interp` and `decimate` instead. Alternatively the function `resample` is designed specifically for fractional resampling. All of these functions apply resampling filters. I should note however, as others have commented the result after going through those resampling filters will not be perfect.

```
>> downsample(upsample(downsample(upsample([1 2 3 4 5 6],3),2),2),3)

ans =

     1     0     3     0     5     0

>> resample(resample([1 2 3 4 5 6],3,2),2,3)

ans =

    1.0154    1.9279    3.1060    3.8622    5.1736    5.7741
```

P.S.  longer sequences will not have nearly as significant error as this example, which is dominated by edge effects.